# How to convert 2D coordinates to 3D coordinates using three.js

Tags: javascript, svg, 3d, three.js

Hi I am working in 2D tool with SVG 2.7.1 , how can I convert the SVG code to SVG coordinated to 3D view using three.js. For creating a scene in 3D I had analysed the tutorial [reference](http://jquery-plugins.net/three-js-javascript-3d-library) .Kindly help me.